# Can't fetch Custom Post Type Data through Custom Query

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a custom taxonomy "Shade Type" which contains two types

1. Ready Mix
2. DCM

I am querying the DCM value to display in WooCommerce tab. My code is fine but I am not getting any values in result.

Here is the code for function:

```
function d_woo_new_product_tab_content6($product) {
  // The DCM Tab Content
  global $product;
  // The Available tab content Here
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'colorshades',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key'     => 'colors_product_id',
        'value'   => $product->id,
        'compare' => '=',
      ),
    ),
    'tax_query'  => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'shade_type',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'dcm'
      )
  )
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()):
foreach( $query->posts as $id ):
//echo 'ID: ' . $id;
$Color_Code = get_post_meta($id, "color_code", true);
$R = get_post_meta($id, "red_code", true);
$G = get_post_meta($id, "green_code", true);
$B = get_post_meta($id, "blue_code", true);
$all_color_product_notification = '';
$image_url = site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/'.rand(1,3).'.png';
echo '<div class="colors_box mb-2">
<a href="javascript:;" class="colorshade" style="background:rgb('.$R.','.$G.','.$B.');"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2'.$id.'">
<img src="'.$image_url.'" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:70px;">
</a>
</div>';
?>
```

Here is my taxonomy code **(Note: Taxonomy is working fine otherwise)**

```
register_taxonomy('shade_type','colorshades',array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Shade Type ', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Shade Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Shade Type' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Shade Type' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Shade Type' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Shade Type' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Shade Type' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Shade Type' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Color Shade Type' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Shade Type with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Shade Type' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Shade Type' )
    ),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => false,
));
```

Also attaching Taxonomy Screenshot below:
[image]

Can someone please help me resolve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The taxonomy query is fine, but what is `colors_product_id`? How is it stored?

Comment: @JacobPeattie It is the Id of the Product to which Values belongs to. DCM values are assigned based on WC product id's.

I have another query which don't contain "'tax_query'  => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'shade_type',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'dcm'
      )"
And It is working fine.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump( $query->request );` right below the `$query = new WP_Query` line. What does the dump output?

Comment: Why is this function accepting `$product` as an argument but also accessing `global $product`? `$product->id` could be undefined for a number of reasons

Comment: @SallyCJ string(629) "SELECT wptr_posts.ID FROM wptr_posts LEFT JOIN wptr_term_relationships ON (wptr_posts.ID = wptr_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wptr_postmeta ON ( wptr_posts.ID = wptr_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wptr_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (53) ) AND ( ( wptr_postmeta.meta_key = 'colors_product_id' AND wptr_postmeta.meta_value = '1697' ) ) AND wptr_posts.post_type = 'colorshades' AND (wptr_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wptr_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wptr_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wptr_posts.ID ....

Comment: @SallyCJ ....ORDER BY FIELD(wptr_posts.ID,'1697','431') DESC, wptr_posts.post_date DESC "

Comment: The SQL query looks good to me, so try removing the `meta_query` from your `$args`, but keep the `tax_query`. If doing so still is not returning any results, then there are no (published/private) `colorshades` posts in the `dcm` term/category.. If you do get one or more results, then it means none of the `colorshades` posts that are in *both* the specified term *and* meta (value)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my query to following worked for me.
I removed the product ID field & called the post taxonomy directly as I didn't need the product Id's.

```
 <?php 
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'colorshades',
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query' => array(
   array(
   'key'     => 'colors_product_id',
    // 'value'   => $product->id,
   // 'compare' => '=',
                                        
   ),
   ),
   'tax_query'   => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'shade_type',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => 'dcm'
      )
     )
   );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```